# MSSQL - GROUP BY Date statement showing wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I have a GROUP BY statement which sort my data based on weeks. The problem here is my data are not being counted for the whole week (Sundays are not counted in)

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductNR] [varchar](14) NULL,
[Location] [int] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductNR, Location, Date)
VALUES 
('12345678911' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678912' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678913' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678914' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678915' ,2, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678916' ,3, '2018-07-22 00:00:00.000'); -- This is a sunday
```

And here is my Sql query in which it retrives the above data split for on 2 weeks when it supposed to be the count for just one week:

```
SELECT count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE
YEAR (CREATED) = '2018'
Group by datepart(wk, created), year(created)
```

**Result:**

```
|Count|
|  5  |
|  1  |
```

**Expected result:**

```
|Count|
|  6  |
```

Comment: Why would you expect the 22nd to be counted in the same week as the 16th instead of the 23rd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE
  CREATED >= '2018-01-01' and CREATED < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY 
  datediff(d, 0, created) / 7
```

If you want to include the week, here is a full script including iso year and iso week

```
DECLARE @year DATE = '2018'

SELECT 
    count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count], 
    datepart(yy, dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, CREATED)/7, 3)) year,
    datepart(iso_week, CREATED) week
FROM Products
WHERE
    CREATED >= dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(d, 3, @year))/7, 0)
    and CREATED < dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, dateadd(d, 3, dateadd(yy, 1, @year)))/7, 0)
GROUP BY 
    datepart(yy, dateadd(wk, datediff(d, 0, CREATED)/7, 3)),
    datepart(iso_week, CREATED)
```

Comment: You sql statement is giving me a wrong count pr week, the numbers are too large

Comment: @MishMish You are right, I was using getdate as testdata and had not changed it back to CREATED. It should work now

Comment: The second sql statement im getting the following: Column 'Products.Created' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
And the first sql statement is still getting too large counts for each week

Comment: Right now it's not showing any errors, but no data either :/

Comment: it should have been yy instead of y in all expressions. Try now

Comment: It's almost correct!
When I check on the count of some of the weeks, I see that It's counting from Monday to Monday instead of Monday to sunday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177096/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-mishmish).

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want `ISO_WEEK` :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE YEAR (CREATED) = '2018'
GROUP BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, created), YEAR(created);
```

Comment: This will have some issues around new year. '2018-12-31' is monday and week 1, which will be counted as year 2018 week 1 even though it belongs to 2019 week 1 using iso_week

Comment: Hello, I just realized that this answer is wrong:
ISO_Week counts from Monday to Monday and WK counts from Sunday to Sunday

Answer (score 0):

The thing is some places start the week on sunday so i think sql counts `2018-07-22` as part of the next week

You can try using [ISO_WEEK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#isoweek-datepart)

```
SELECT count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE
YEAR (CREATED) = '2018'
Group by datepart(ISO_WEEK, created), year(created)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Set Monday as the first day of week using following query:
SET DATEFIRST 1

*@MishMish Here is the code snippet , I used*

```
<!-- language: sql -->
USE tempdb
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Products')
    DROP TABLE Products

CREATE TABLE [Products](
[ProductNR] [varchar](14) NULL,
[Location] [int] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductNR, Location, Date)
VALUES 
('12345678911' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678912' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678913' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678914' ,1, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678915' ,2, '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000'), -- Monday
('12345678916' ,3, '2018-07-22 00:00:00.000'); -- This is a sunday

--SELECT  datepart(wk, Date) as Week, * FROM Products

--Count Before Setting First Date To Monday
SET DATEFIRST 7  -- Sunday ( default, U.S. English)

SELECT count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE
YEAR (Date) = '2018'
Group by datepart(wk, Date), year(Date) 

--CHANGE FIRST Date To Monday
SET DATEFIRST 1

--Count AFTER Setting First Date To Monday
SELECT count(Distinct ProductNR) AS [Count]
FROM Products
WHERE
YEAR (Date) = '2018'
Group by datepart(wk, Date), year(Date)
```

Comment: It hasn't changed anything